# Is there any way to remove automatically all leading and trailing spaces in text fields

Tags: database, delphi, ado

In a Delphi application which uses TADODataSet components to access to an Access database, there is any way to delete leading and trailing spaces from text fields when record is written to disk? or perhaps when retrieving the data, but without modifying all my queries.

I mean in ADO engine, without coding myself using `Trim()` in `BeforePost` on every table.

Comment: Is the `FixedChar` property set to `False`?

Comment: I tried to add this parameter to my `ConnectionString` and I get an error: _Could not find installable ISAM_. I can't find documentation about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With all the limitations you've put up... No

My advice would be to code a BeforePost event just once and link all tables to the same beforepost event.

**In the objectinspector**

```
Table1.BeforePost:= TrimFieldsBeforePost;
Table2.BeforePost:= TrimFieldsBeforePost;
....
```

**In your code**

```
procedure TMyForm.TrimFieldsBeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i:= 0;
  while i < Dataset.Fields.Count do begin
    if (Dataset.Fields[i].DataType in
      [ftString, FtMemo, ftFixedChar, ftWideString,FtVariant, ftFixedWideChar, ftWideMemo]) then begin
      Dataset.Fields[i].AsString:= Trim(Dataset.Fields[i].AsString);
    end;
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Because all my editing forms inherits from the same parent, and the DataSet it's there, I do the trick easily.

Comment: But one question, why do you include _Variants_ type? (also you misspelled FmtMemo :-)

Comment: @Juanmi, I copy-pasted it from the source Ah well I guess I should change my name to `butterfingers`. I included the variant, because variants can hold a string (among other things) and if it does not then the trim will not hurt.

Answer (score 5):

Create your own `TADODataSet` descendant component (`TJuanADODataSet`) and incorporate the behavior you want into the `BeforePost` event.  Refactor to make all the existing `TADODataSet`s into `TJuanADODataset`s.

Comment: Good idea, perhaps for a new project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched Access in years, but isn't there an auto-trim feature on Text fields?